# Reactive extensions: modifying existing stream that is processed slowly

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive, reactivex

I am learning Rx and I'm attempting to translate the following problem into an Rx pipeline. It looks like there should be a simple Rx solution to this but I can't find it. Here is some simple C# code to demonstrate the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Item = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, string>;

namespace Sample
{
    class Test
    {
        readonly object _sync = new object();

        readonly List<Item> _workList = new List<Item>();

        public void Update(IEnumerable<Item> items)
        {
            lock(_sync)
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    bool found = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < _workList.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        if (_workList[i].Key == item.Key)
                        {
                            _workList[i] = item;
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!found)
                    {
                        _workList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            void ThreadMethod(object _)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Item? item = null;

                    lock (_sync)
                    {
                        if (_workList.Any())
                        {
                            item = _workList[0];
                            _workList.RemoveAt(0);
                        }
                    }

                    if (item.HasValue)
                    {
                        var str = $"{item.Value.Key} : {item.Value.Value}";

                        Console.WriteLine($"Start {str}");
                        Thread.Sleep(5000); // simluate work
                        Console.WriteLine($"End {str}");
                    }
                }
            }

            var thread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

An 'update' event consists of a list of Key/Value pairs. The update is merged with an existing list with the following rules. *It is not guaranteed that every known key will appear in every update*

- If the key is found, the value is replaced at the current position in the list. The previous value will be discarded and is not processed.
- If the key is not found the item is added to the end of the list

A separate thread processes the list *one item at a time*. This processing takes some time (simulated by a Thread.sleep). Items are removed from the beginning of the list when they are processed.

As you can see, during the processing of a single item, items in the backlog can mutate in place. The point is that only the very latest value received will be processed for each key but the order of keys in the backlog cannot change (except when a key is processed it is removed from the list. If the key is reintroduced in the list it is added to the end).

My latest attempt with Rx was to feed the update into a Scan function that turned previously unknown keys into subjects and then feed new values for each key into it's corresponding subject before combining all the latest values but it didn't quite work.

Please refrain from discussing non-Rx solutions. The simple code above will do the job but I'd like to learn if there is an Rx solution.

I'm working in C# (System.Reactive) but I'll happily accept solutions in other dialects of Rx.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mechanisms you will need to accomplish your objective. The first is a map that gives you the latest value of an emitted item. The second is the `flatMap()` operator.

```
Map<String, String> currentSourceValue = new HashMap<>();
```

I am using `String` as the data type and `keyOf()` and `valOf()` methods.

This method will update the map with the latest value. If there was already a current value, replace it and return the `empty()` observable.

```
synchronized Observable<String> setLatestValue( String s ) {
    String r = currentSourceValue.put( keyOf( s ), valOf( s ) );
    return r == null ? Observable.just( s ) : Observable.empty();
}
```

This method will extract the value from the map if it can be emitted.

```
synchronized Observable<String> getLatestValue( String s ) {
    String r = currentSourceValue.remove( keyOf( s ) );
    return r == null ? Observable.empty() : Observable.just( r );
}
```

This will allow the latest value to be emitted

```
source
 .flatMap( s -> setLatestValue( s ) )
 .observeOn( processingScheduler )
 .flatMap( s -> getLatestValue( s ), 1 )
 .subscribe( s -> process( s ) );
```

The first `flatMap()` operator updates the latest value of the incoming stream. If there is an item already in the queue for this key, then the `empty()` observable is returned so that no space is consumed in the downstream chain.

The second `flatMap()` operator works on the processing thread. The second parameter to `flatMap()` says that items should be processed one at a time, without parallelism. It will emit a value if it is present in the map, or no value if it is not, and clear out the map entry. In theory, the second `flatMap()` could just emit a value but there is some non-determinism when the observer chain hops from one thread to another upstream.

The `synchronized` keyword indicates that the actions on the map are atomic, and to prevent a value from being removed from the map downstream, just as it was added to the map upstream.

This solution works in a way that is similar to the `groupBy()` operator, but it handles the situation where you only want to process the latest value for a given key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bob. I appreciate the answer and it is very educational. I had toyed with the idea of using an external dictionary but not actually tried it because it introduces explicit mutable state and requires synchronisation. I have been trying to come up with something 'pure'. Using flatMap with Observable.empty to avoid emitting an event is a great technique.

Comment: I have had to implement something like this several times. You can create an operator that does this operation. Start with a class `GroupByLatest<K,V>` that holds a `Map<K,V>` and does these steps. Then, add a `Transform` method that can be used as an argument to the `compose()` operator. The question is whether this capability is widely enough needed to warrant inclusion in the RxJava library or extension libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and see how it looks

Answer (score 1):

This will work, though I'm not the biggest fan of it.

I viewed this as a producer/consumer situation: One thread creating work, another doing it. The `producer` subject represents the thread that adds work. Everything else represents the consumer side of things. If you were going to `class` it up, `producer` would go in one class, and everything else in the other.

`completedKeys` holds keys that are done, so the state for that key gets ejected: a new item with that key would go to the back of the line. `readyGate` represents when the consumer is newly available to work on the next thing. Combining that with the latest of what to work on is the tricky part. `WithLatestFrom` works great until you get an empty list. The `.Where().FirstAsync()` does the waiting part nicely.

The key to all of this is `GroupByUntil`: That groups things, and they naturally fall into the order the keys were first added, which is what you want. The `Until` clause means we can close the observable, which would make a new item with an old key go the back of the line. `DynamicCombinedLatest` turns all those observables into a List, which is effectively you're state.

Anyhow, here you go:

```
var producer = new Subject<Item>();
var readyGate = new Subject<Unit>();
var completedKeys = new Subject<int>();

var Process = new Action<Item>(kvp =>
{
    var str = $"{kvp.Key} : {kvp.Value}";

    Console.WriteLine($"Start {str}");
    Thread.Sleep(500); // simluate work
    Console.WriteLine($"End {str}");
});

var groups = producer
    .GroupByUntil(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp, go => completedKeys.Where(k => k == go.Key))
    .DynamicCombineLatest();

var q = groups.Publish(_groups => readyGate
        .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .WithLatestFrom(groups, (_, l) => l)
        .SelectMany(l => l.Count == 0
            ? _groups.Where(g => g.Count > 0).FirstAsync()
            : Observable.Return(l)
        )
    )
    .Subscribe(l =>
    {
        var kvp = l[0];
        completedKeys.OnNext(kvp.Key);
        Process(kvp);
        readyGate.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    });


//Runner code:
producer.OnNext(new Item(1, "1-a"));
producer.OnNext(new Item(1, "1-b"));

producer.OnNext(new Item(2, "2-a"));
producer.OnNext(new Item(2, "2-b"));

readyGate.OnNext(Unit.Default);

await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)); //to test if 1 gets done again and goes to the back of the line.
producer.OnNext(new Item(1, "1-c"));
```

And `DynamicCombinedLatest` is this (uses nuget package `System.Collections.Immutable`):

```
public static IObservable<List<T>> DynamicCombineLatest<T>(this IObservable<IObservable<T>> source)
{
    return source
        .SelectMany((o, i) => o.Materialize().Select(notification => (observableIndex: i, notification: notification)))
        .Scan((exception: (Exception)null, dict: ImmutableDictionary<int, T>.Empty), (state, t) => t.notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnNext
            ? ((Exception)null, state.dict.SetItem(t.observableIndex, t.notification.Value))
            : t.notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted
                ? ((Exception)null, state.dict.Remove(t.observableIndex))
                : (t.notification.Exception, state.dict)
        )
        .Select(t => t.exception == null
            ? Notification.CreateOnNext(t.dict)
            : Notification.CreateOnError<ImmutableDictionary<int, T>>(t.exception)
        )
        .Dematerialize()
        .Select(dict => dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work on this answer. Now I know why I was having such a hard time coming up with a pure Rx solution.

Comment: No problem. I hope something like `DynamicCombinedLatest` gets worked in at some point. Working with `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` directly can be quite hard.